# Exist an element $v_0 \in M$, $v_0 \neq 0$, and $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $E(v_0) = 0$ and $H(v_0) = \lambda \cdot v_0$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Let $A$ be an asociative $\mathbb{C}$-algebra with three generators $E$, $H$, $F$, and three defining relations$$HE - EH = 2E,\text{ }HF - FH = -2F,\text{ }EF - FE = H.$$Let $M$ be a nonzero finite dimensional representation of $A$. Does there exist an element $v_0 \in M$, $v_0 \neq 0$, and $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $E(v_0) = 0$ and $H(v_0) = \lambda \cdot v_0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean $HE - EH = 2E$ and $HF - FH = -2F$? I can't comment to ask, so I'll answer both the version you posted and what I believe you meant.

## What I think you meant: $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$

In this situation, $\{H,E,F\}$ is a basis for $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$. Your question is a standard result in the representation theory of this algebra, but let's assume you haven't seen it.

First, since $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$ is simple, we know that given any representation $\pi: \mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C}) \rightarrow \mathfrak{gl}(M)$, that $\pi$ is an isomorphism onto its image. Now, $\pi(H)$ is a semisimple element of the algebra, and the preservation of Jordan forms tells us that $\pi(H)$ is also semisimple as a linear map on $M$, i.e. diagonable.

Now, if $M = \bigoplus_{\lambda \in \mathbb{C}} M_\lambda$ is the decomposition of $M$ into eigenspaces for the action of $H$, then taking $v \in M_\lambda$ gives:

$$H.(E.v) = [H,E].v + E.(H.V) = 2E.v + \lambda E.v = (\lambda + 2)E.v$$

Since $M$ is assumed to be finite dimensional, there can be only finitely many non-zero eigenspaces for $H$. Since $E$ maps eigenspaces to higher eigenspaces, eventually it must (by dimension concerns) map some eigenspace to 0.

While I've mentioned the main ideas, this is covered in greater detail in chapters 6 and 7 of Humphreys' Introductions to Lie Algebras and Representation Theory.

## What you wrote

Much as for the previous question, we'll consider the Lie algebra $L$ generated by $\{H,E,F\}$, which now has generating relations:

$$[H,E] = [H,F] = 0, [E,F] = H$$

This Lie algebra is nilpotent (since its derived algebra is central), so our goal is to use Engel's Theorem. Let $\pi$ be our representation. Then $\pi(L)$ is also nilpotent. Engel's Theorem now applies, and it provides us with a flag on $M$, $M_1 \subset M_2 \subset \dots \subset M_k$, with $L.M_k \subset M_{k-1}$. That is to say: there exists a basis for $M$ in which $\pi(L)$ consists solely of upper triangular matrices. Then the first basis vector satisfies the condition, with $\lambda = 0$.